# Printing text next to a form field in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, printing

I'm having a bit of trouble with this assignment and would like your help.
We are meant to create a product registration form page with all the regular expressions and everything and display the correct error when the regexes don't match.

I am trying to print a tick or say OK next to a form field but I can't get the right function.

The "Please enter product ...." is activated by jquery with a slideUp and slideDown function with onblur on the text field.

So I want to display OK where the red circle is after you click away from it, and then if you change it to something that doesn't match the OK disappears and my alert shows up. So this is my code so far:

My html form:

```
<div>
<input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Name" name="name" onblur="return validateProductName()"> <p class ="p11" id="p1"></p>
  <p class="name-help">Please enter a product name between 1-50 characters.</p>
</div>
```

My css:

```
.p11 {
float: right;}
```

My jQuery:

```
$(".name").focus(function(){
  $(".name-help").slideDown(500);
}).blur(function(){
  $(".name-help").slideUp(500);
});
```

And then my JavaScript:

```
    // Function to validate product name
function validateProductName() {

    // if statement for product name
    if (document.myForm.name.value.trim().search(pName) == -1) {
    
        alert("Invalid product name. Please note: product name should have 1-50 characters.");
        
        
    } else {
        
        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "OK";
    }
    
}
```

So, it prints the OK in between the field on the right side, but I want it right next to the field like I showed in the picture and I can't get this to work! I want it to disappear if I go back to the form and put something wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, you have no problem with the `jQuery` itself, you have a problem of showing it next to input box. So,

Create a `<span id='tick'>` tag after the `input` field

And once it passes the validation, use jquery to show the `tick`

```
$('#tick').html('whatever you want');
```

**EDIT:** You **dont** have to include the `float:left` on span

Check out the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/duqv9c9L/1/)

**EDIT:**

In this validation function, just show and hide according to the validation results

```
     // Function to validate product name
    function validateProductName() {

        // if statement for product name
        if (document.myForm.name.value.trim().search(pName) == -1) {

          document.getElementById("tick").style.display = 'none'; // to hide the OK text if enterd the wrong input  


        } else {

            document.getElementById("tick").innerHTML = "OK"; //NOTE: This is for showing the ok text
  document.getElementById("tick").style.display= "block";
        }

    }
```

Comment: That didn't really work for me, my jQuery is only for that slideUp and slideDown. I have to show the tick or the correct message using JavaScript. What I did: created a `<spand id="tick"></span>` with no message inside, then called it with `document.getElementById("tick").innerHTML = "OK"`, however, it shows the OK under the field and when I go back to the field and put an wrong value, it still shows the ok... Thank you anyway :)

Comment: checkout my edit, you just have to hide or show according to the validation results

Comment: Weirdly, I got it displaying next to the field with this CSS `#tick {float: right; display: inline-block; width: 0px; }` and then added the `document.getElementById("tick").style.display = 'none';` and it works! However, when I click away with the right input it shows OK, I got back put something wrong it disappears, then if I put something correct and click away it doesn't show the OK anymore... :s

Comment: Did you include document.getElementById("tick").style.display= "block"; if user types right product name?

Comment: you can simply use jquery too in that place like $('#tick').show()

Comment: Yes sorry! Hadn't included the `document.getElementById("tick").style.display= "block";`. Now it's working fine! Thank you very much foir helping me out :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a span wherever you want your tick to be displayed and they do this,

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  if ($("#txtname").val() == "") //can be any check
  {

    $("#g").attr("style", "display:block;width:20px");

  } else {
    $("#g").attr("style", "display:none;width:20px;");
  }



})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="txtname" style="display:inline-block" placeholder="enter name" />
<img id="g" style="width:50px;display:none;" src="http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/04/02/10/19/check-303494_640.png" />
<br/>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="click to submit" />
```

Comment: At the moment I don't need to add images, but will definitely use it next time it's required. Got it solved with the first answer, thanks for helping anyways!

Answer (score 0):

This should work-

```
<script src="jq.js"></script>
<div>
<input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="input"> <span class ="p11" id="p1"></span>
  <p class="name-help">Please enter a product name between 1-50 characters.</p>
</div>
<style>
p11 {
float: right;}
</style>
<script>
$(".name").focus(function(){
  $(".name-help").slideDown(500);
}).blur(function(){
  $(".name-help").slideUp(500);
  validateProductName()
});
</script>
<script>
    // Function to validate product name
function validateProductName() {
    // if statement for product name
    if (document.getElementById("input").value.trim() == "" || document.getElementById("input").value.length > 50 ) {

        alert("Invalid product name. Please note: product name should have 1-50 characters.");
       document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "";


    } else {

        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "OK";
    }

}
</script>
```